# VerbTeX Android App

Tags: graphics, android, verbtex

I am using VerbTeX LaTeX editor and unable to insert pictures in document. Anybody suggest me[image: Screenshot of my code.]

Answer (score 3):

VerbTeX doesn't run LaTeX on your phone.  All files are uploaded to an online server, VerbTeX runs LaTeX on your document in that server, and then the output `.pdf` is downloaded back to your phone.  This means that the path `/storage` doesn't exist there, thus your image won't be found.

To use images you have to place them manually in the folder of your project so that when the files are uploaded to the remote server, the images are uploaded as well.  On my phone, the folder is located in `/storage/Android/data/verbosus.verbtex/files/Local/<project-name>`.  I pasted an image file in there and (after quite a while, to upload and then download the whole thing) the `.pdf` file showed up correctly.